# IBM Watson Studio: save data from a notebook in a IBM mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ibm-watson

I have a machine learning project in IBM Watson Studio which should save data in a mongoDB (as IBM Service). How can I connect from my notebook in IBM Studio to the mongoDB and save data there?

Comment: can you please specify what is the programming language?
What have you tried and what is failing?
Spark or non-spark?